# How set Exchange 2010 mailbox limits by groups

Tags: exchange-2010

I am starting to migrate about 1000 user mailboxes from an Exchange 2003 cluster to a new Exchange 2010 SP2 and I'm trying to figure out how to set mailbox size limits based on user roles. My idea is to divide users into 3 roles by Active Directory groups, High usage (1 GB limit), Medium (512 MB limit) and Low (256 MB limit). As Exchange will distribute mailboxes automatically between detabases during migration, how can I set mailbox limits by user groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably place the users in separate databases based on their usage needs. The mailbox limits would be defined in each database.